# How to remove few words from end of a sentence?

Tags: php

I have something like :

" YAKUGAKU ZASSHI-JOURNAL OF THE PHARMACEUTICAL SOCIETY OF JAPAN **YAKUGAKU ZASSHI** "

and want to remove the second "YAKUGAKU ZASSHI" (which is in bold) from it. How can I do it?

I have a list that in each row, something is repeated at the first and at the end, and I want to remove the ones which are repeated at the end. How can I do it?

UPDATE:

I found the solution, so just wanted to update my question in case someone had the same problem.

So actually I am trying to get the list of the journals and their abbreviation from :  http://images.webofknowledge.com/WOK46/help/WOS/Y_abrvjt.html

and then show them as  Journal name : abbreviation

but what I got from the website was werired becuase the definition lists DT and DD tags were not closed.

So actually I had 2 strings , $dd and $dt. $dd was repeated at the $dt.so this is what I did to remove the duplicate:

```
 $length=strlen($dd); // get length of the dd
 $ddN=explode(' ', $dd); // split the dd and put in new variable called $ddN
 $extra=$ddN[0];  // get the first word of dd
 $pos=strripos($dt,$extra); // find the position of the last occurrence of $extra in $dt, which is first word of $dd
 $result=substr($dt,$pos,-$length); //removing the duplicate from end of the dd
 echo '"' . $result . '"' . '  :  ' . '"' . $dd . '"' . '<br>';
```

Comment: Is the second part always in bold? And are there always leading and trailing spaces?

Comment: Explode on space and hyphen, count the number of word instances as `$count`, then replace them with an empty string starting from the right, `($count - 1)` times.

Comment: (Note it is common here for people to ask what you have tried. If you can edit in your current attempts into your code, that is appreciated - hopefully you didn't ask a question before trying anything!)

Comment: I found a solution and updated my question.@halfer

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to eat regular expresions, here is small found [solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/8810).

```
$textWithoutLastWord = preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $words);
```

Or using functions:

```
$lastSpacePosition = strrpos($text, ' ');
$textWithoutLastWord = substr($text, 0, $lastSpacePosition);
```

Comment: thanks, I found a solution and updated my question with the answer.

Comment: care about performance of your solution. If u will have thousands rows server will down

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand - you want to avoid duplicate words in the title (sentence).
This can be achieved with something like:

```
<?php

//Our input string - can be from database, or whatever, trimmed from ending/trailing spaces
$string = trim("YAKUGAKU ZASSHI-JOURNAL OF THE PHARMACEUTICAL SOCIETY OF JAPAN YAKUGAKU ZASSHI");
//Convert title to array of words
$array = explode (" ", $string);
//How many elements we have in array
$count = count($array); 
//Remove the last 2
unset($array[$count-1]);
unset($array[$count-2]);
print_r ($array);
?>
```

Check this [fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AlUz0H).

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution anbd updated my question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, so just wanted to update my question in case someone had the same problem.

So actually I am trying to get the list of the journals and their abbreviation from : http://images.webofknowledge.com/WOK46/help/WOS/Y_abrvjt.html

and then show them as Journal name : abbreviation

but what I got from the website was werired becuase the definition lists DT and DD tags were not closed.

So actually I had 2 strings , $dd and $dt. $dd was repeated at the $dt.so this is what I did to remove the duplicate:

```
       $length=strlen($dd); // get length of the dd
       $ddN=explode(' ', $dd); // split the dd and put in new variable called $ddN
       $extra=$ddN[0];  // get the first word of dd
       $pos=strripos($dt,$extra); // find the position of the last occurrence of $extra in $dt, which is first word of $dd
       $result=substr($dt,$pos,-$length); //removing the duplicate from end of the dd
       echo '"' . $result . '"' . '  :  ' . '"' . $dd . '"' . '<br>';
```